# Could not import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfReader

Tags: java, android, android-studio, pdf, itext

I want to use iText PdfReader class. For that I add library dependency com.itextpdf:itext-pdfa:5.5.10 and then I import it in my MainActivity.
`import com.itextpdf.text.pdf. ??` there I couldn't find PdfReader. There are other references but not PdfReader.
[image]
Please help me how I can add this ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

At present, you are using itext-pdfa-5.5.10.jar. Whereas, `PdfReader` is available in itextpdf-5.5.10. Use correct jar and your issue will be resolved. For Android, [iTextG](http://developers.itextpdf.com/itextg-android) is recommended.

**UPDATE (For Android):**

```
compile 'com.itextpdf:itextg:5.5.10'
```

**For Other Platforms:**

**Gradle:**

```
compile 'com.itextpdf:itextpdf:5.5.10'
```

**Maven:** [iText 5.5.10](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.itextpdf/itextpdf/5.5.10)

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
    <artifactId>itextpdf</artifactId>
    <version>5.5.10</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: As the OP uses Android, an iTextG version would be more apropos.

Comment: @mkl thanks for pointing that out..I have used iText for desktop/web-based applications.

Comment: @Junaidumar Accept the answer if you are satisfied with the solution.

Comment: I did. Thanks Again Man

Comment: I'd like to add that there seems to be some confusion in the name. The 'A' in pdfa stands for 'PDF/A' also known as ISO 19005. This is a long-term archiving standard based on PDF. The 'G' in iTextG comes from Google App Engine, where the port was first developed for, but the iTextG port can also be used on Android and that's what it is most used for currently.

Answer (score 0):

You can try put this on the Gradle. It Works for me.

```
compile 'com.itextpdf:itext-pdfa:5.5.10'
```